# How to detect that which add-on has been enabled in IE9?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

How can I detect whether or not an add-on has been enabled in IE9 using C#?

Comment: In what context? Web application, WinForms with browser control, etc ..

Answer (score 2):

your question is just the opposite of this one -

[How to detect that an add-on has been disabled by the user in IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433581/how-to-detect-that-an-add-on-has-been-disabled-by-the-user-in-ie9)

take a look..